# Image saved locally not displaying on github wiki

Tags: github, markdown

I have a local copy of a github repository inside another repository which i edit on vscode. I can commit changes just fine and i could also display images saved locally by simply writing
`![](/pictures/image.png)`
then, since i already had those images in another folder inside the main repo, i changed the path to
`![](\C:\Users\Ale\Documents\GitHub\asdrus_stuff\resourcepack\assets\ded\textures\gui\recipes\amethyst_resonance_shield.png)`

this made the image not appear on github, i googled possible reasons and it seems the issue is i need to use `/`, not `\`.
So i tried this
`![](/resourcepack/assets/ded/textures/gui/recipes/amethyst_resonance_shield.png)`
which still doesn't work because i think the root path the wiki repo is looking for is wrong, BUT i cant' change the location on my pc of the image folder because of other technical limitations (people that know how minecraft resourcepacks work will know)

Random idea i though of, maybe use the image hosted on the github repo in the wiki repo, though this doesn't work
`[](https://github.com/asdru22/Deep-Descent/blob/main/resourcepack/assets/ded/textures/gui/recipes/amethyst_resonance_shield.png)`